# EF Entity Can not be updated or deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am building a Task management ( day to day task management, not system tasks).

Here is my `TaskListEntity` - in this table `TaskId` is the PK

```
public partial class TaskList
{

    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string TaskType { get; set; }
    public string TaskNote { get; set; }
    public string HandlerId { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Remind { get; set; }
    public string TaskSubType { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public string HandlerId2 { get; set; }
    public string HandlerId3 { get; set; }
    public string HandlerId4 { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

When user ticks Completed, I want to update the instance so I did this

```
UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();
TaskList task = uow.Tasks.GetAll().Where(t => t.TaskId == taskId).FirstOrDefault();
task.Completed = true;

uow.Tasks.Update(task);
uow.Complete();
```

I'm getting this weird error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Completed' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. '

The property `Completed` is no Key and not even a FK. I just can't think of why this is happening. What am I missing here? I even added this to see if it helps

```
[Key]
public int TaskId { get; set; }
```

Just to make sure system sees `TaskId` as the primary key not the `Completed` field.

I have been battling with this for hours now. Can someone please help me?

Here is the Update Method

```
  public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {

        try
        {
            Context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                        validationError.PropertyName,
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you call `Ignore(x => x.Completed)` in your `DbContext`?

Comment: I know that EF could have problem if an entity doesn't have primary keys setted as Identity, is TaskId an identity?

Comment: What is the `uow.Tasks.Update()` method doing? Could you please share the code of it so we can take a look at it?

Comment: Yes TaskId is an Identity

Comment: Hi bassfader, Updated the question with the Update method.

Comment: You should first check it in the database... is `Completed` actually part of the primary key? If so, why? How did you start creating your model? Do you use automatic/manual Migrations?

Comment: For diagnosis, try setting something else (like priority).